# Get the clicked rectangle in 2d array

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, uniformgrid

I have a 2D array that contains rectangles. They are stored in a dynamic UniformGrid. How do I find out which rectangle in the array was MouseDown?

I tried this but I keep getting [0,0]:

```cs
if (e.OriginalSource is Shape s)
{
    cellRow = (int)s.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
    cellColumn = (int)s.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);
    rectangle[cellRow,cellColumn].Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
```

And this is how I generated the rectangles:

```cs
rectangle = new Rectangle[rowcol, rowcol];
for (int x = 0; x < rowcol; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < rowcol; y++)
    {
        rectangle[y, x] = new Rectangle { Stroke = Brushes.Black, StrokeThickness = 0.5, Fill = Brushes.White };
        GameUniformGrid.Children.Add(rectangle[y, x]);
    }
}
```

The MouseDown event in xaml:
`<UniformGrid x:Name="GameUniformGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="272" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="272" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Rectangle.MouseDown="ToggleGrid"/>`

Comment: Grid.Row and Grid.Column are attached properties used by the Grid element. UniformGrid doesn't use or even know them. You should actually have a view model with a rectangle item class with row and column index, and visualize them by an ItemsControl. That said, a workaround maybe to get the index of the Rectangle in the Children collection of the UniformGrid. Then divide the index by the number of columns to get its row index. The remainder of the devision then is the coumn index.

Comment: I got it from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51807534/is-there-a-way-to-get-current-column-and-row-index-pair-of-where-rectangle-is-cl

But anyways, what should I do then?

Comment: @Nothing, you missed the part, where Row and Column are assigned: `rectangle[x, y].SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, x);rectangle[x, y].SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, y);`

Comment: @ASh I added that before... But it just gave me an error when generating the grid saying that it won't respond and I found out that the row and column properties are 0...

Comment: why are you initializing "new Rectangle[rowcol, rowcol]" in this way? why not using row and col?what if rowcol=0 then it will obviously create [0,0] and loop runs only once

Comment: @TAHA SULTAN TEMURI rowcol is not equal to 0 it can only be 5-20. I did rowcol because I know that the rows and columns are the same. Why will I create another variable if both of them stays the same?

Comment: @Clemens From the xaml, I can see that there is a Grid.Row and Grid.Column... Anyways, thanks for your help I will try using an ItemsControl later :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with initializing a rectangle,
When you work with [multidimentional array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays) you have some rows and column and what you are doing is using row only in both row,column.
What if rowcol =0 ? the loop will not run because this condition.

> x < rowcol (0<0);

You should

```
rectangle = new Rectangle[row, col];
    for (int x = 0; x < row; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < col; y++)
        {
            rectangle[y, x] = new Rectangle { Stroke = Brushes.Black, StrokeThickness = 0.5, Fill = Brushes.White };
            GameUniformGrid.Children.Add(rectangle[y, x]);
        }
    }
```

**(For example)**

> where row = 2 ,col =2

Comment: I can initialize the rectangle and there's no problem with that. What I need is to find out which rectangle in the array was MouseDown. Is it possible to get it by using sender or how should I do it?